# Find duplicate entries in a text file using shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to find duplicate *.sh entry mention in a text file(test.log) and delete it, using shell program. Since the path is different so uniq -u always print duplicate entry even though there are two first_prog.sh entry in a text file

```
cat test.log       
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/first_prog.sh        
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/second_prog.sh    
/mnt/abc/my_shellprog/test/first_prog.sh           
/mnt/abc/my_shellprog/test/third_prog.sh
```

output:

```
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/first_prog.sh    
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/second_prog.sh    
/mnt/abc/my_shellprog/test/third_prog.sh
```

I tried couple of way using few command but dont have idea on how to get above output.

```
rev test.log | cut -f1 -d/ | rev | sort | uniq -d
```

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` shines for these kind of tasks but here in a non awk solution,

```
$ sed 's|.*/|& |' file | sort -k2 -u | sed 's|/ |/|'

/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/first_prog.sh
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/second_prog.sh
/mnt/abc/my_shellprog/test/third_prog.sh
```

or, if your path is balanced (the same number of parents for all files)

```
$ sort -t/ -k5 -u file

/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/first_prog.sh
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/second_prog.sh
/mnt/abc/my_shellprog/test/third_prog.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Karakfa, This was interesting, was finding it difficult to use sed but looks like we can still get this done in sed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk for this by splitting fields on `/` and using `$NF` (last field) in an associative array:

```
awk -F/ '!seen[$NF]++' test.log

/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/first_prog.sh
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/second_prog.sh
/mnt/abc/my_shellprog/test/third_prog.sh
```

Comment: Ok..didnt looked in awk but looks much easier that using sed. 
Thanks Anubhava this will ignite me to study more about awk as a beginner.

Comment: yeah that right how i dont have any ordering issues so that was ok.

Comment: Yes you don't have ordering issue but but using 3 commands instead of a simple one is not easy to justify. Not to forget unix paths can have spaces also and it will break the `sed | sort`

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '!/my_shellprog\/test\/first/' file
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/first_prog.sh        
/mnt/abc/shellprog/test/second_prog.sh    
/mnt/abc/my_shellprog/test/third_prog.sh
```

Comment: The path is not fixed after 3rd level (my_shellprog). It can have any number of ' / ' so simple awk will not work. Your solution for above problem will get solve though